# How can I use the varible inside array map to control style on Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using `Materil UI` 4.11. We know with Material UI, if we want to use a varible inside the style setting, we can do in this way:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    testStyle: {
        width: ({ ElementWidth }) => `${ElementWidth * 100}%`,
    }
})
```

and inside component, we set the varible and call the class:

```
const styleProps = {
    ElementWidth,
}
const classes = useStyles(styleProps)
<Box className={classes.testStyle}>
    element
</Box>
```

My question is if I want to use a varible inside one array map, how can I set it?
The array is like:

```
const itemArr = [
    {name:"a",successStatus:true,},
    {name:"b",successStatus:false},
    {name:"c",successStatus:true},
]
```

component:

```
<Box>
    {itemArr.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <Box key={index}>
                <Typography className={classes.successStatusStyle}>
                    {item.name}
                </Typography>
            </Box>
        )
    })}
</Box>
```

What I want to set in the class is the color will be different based on the `item.successStatus` value:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    successStatusStyle:{
        color: ({ successStatus }) => successStatus ? theme.palette.success.main : theme.palette.error.main
    }
})
```

How can I pass the `item.successStatus` to useStyles, so each item will have dynamic color based on `successStatus`?

I know with inline-style, I can change the color, like `style={{ color: successStatus ? "green" : "blue" }}`, but the reason I want to set it inside useStyles is I want to use the pattern from my theme or the default pattern from Material UI. So I cannot use inline-style here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not pick a class name based on the value of `successStatus`?

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    successStyle:{
        color: theme.palette.success.main
    },
    errorStyle:{
        color: theme.palette.error.main
    },
});

<Box>
    {itemArr.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <Box key={index}>
                <Typography className={ item.successStatus ? classes.successStyle: classes.errorStyle }>
                    {item.name}
                </Typography>
            </Box>
        )
    })}
</Box>
```

Comment: this works well for 2 options but what if there are several? I want to map over tags and output a different style for each tag.

Comment: @Ron Are you having issues adapting this to use multiple styles? You may create a function `getStyleFromTag(tag, styles)` which will give the correct classname for eash tag.

Comment: actually it was a combo of needing to make it lowercase and me misunderstanding dot notation on objects. I was using MUI and was trying to do `classes.item.tag` when it needed to be `classes[item.tag.toLowerCase()]`. But thanks to your comment I tried a few things and figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

***an alternative solution***

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    successStyle:{
        color: theme.palette.success.main
    },
    errorStyle:{
        color: theme.palette.error.main
    },
});


   <Box>
        {itemArr.map((item, index) => {
            const colorClass = item.successStatus ? classes.successStyle: classes.errorStyle;
            return (
                <Box key={index}>
                    <Typography className={colorClass}>
                        {item.name}
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            )
        })}
    </Box>
```